# Opensearch deleted documents not freeing up disk space and search performance getting degraded

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

We are using opensearch having elasticsearch v7.10.2 and we have a large index where we index data regularly and delete the data(which gets a month old) regularly as well but over a period of time now we are experiencing a degradation in search performance in our queries where we mostly use has_child queries, I want to know that the docs deleted are they still reciting in my index and are they still consuming the resources, if yes, then how can I get them removed, below I have attached a few stats.

GET _cat/segments?index=segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571&s=docs.deleted

A few of my segments have reached 5GB as well, here attaching only a few segments example for better understanding

```
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 83 r x.x.x.x _36u6 148830  4566709 5083016    4.2gb 292024 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 83 p x.x.x.x _36u6 148830  4566709 5083016    4.2gb 292024 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 84 p x.x.x.x  _37hm 149674  4569844 5127644    4.4gb 290112 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 84 r x.x.x.x _37hm 149674  4569838 5127650    4.4gb 290112 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 40 p x.x.x.x _30oh 140849  3765550 5460181    4.7gb 292616 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 40 r x.x.x.x  _30oh 140849  3765544 5460187    4.7gb 292616 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 29 r x.x.x.x _2ygs 137980  3359481 5519471    4.9gb 287504 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 29 p x.x.x.x  _2ygs 137980  3359481 5519471    4.9gb 287504 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 13 p x.x.x.x  _2u1h 132245  2731374 5565823      4gb 289480 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 13 r x.x.x.x _2u1h 132245  2731372 5565825      4gb 289480 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 57 p x.x.x.x  _3bx3 155415  4144634 5615761    4.5gb 304728 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 57 r x.x.x.x _3bx3 155415  4144620 5615775    4.5gb 304728 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 10 r x.x.x.x  _2yau 137766  3535782 5821903    4.6gb 290072 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 10 p x.x.x.x _2yau 137766  3535778 5821907    4.6gb 290072 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 5  r x.x.x.x _2vsz 134531  3052529 5940943      5gb 287288 true  true  8.7.0 false
segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571 5  p x.x.x.x  _2vsz 134531  3052529 5940943      5gb 287288 true  true  8.7.0 false
```

GET segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571/_stats

```
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 200,
    "successful" : 200,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_all" : {
    "primaries" : {
      "docs" : {
        "count" : 2764210965,
        "deleted" : 768121801
      },
      "store" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 1882036902899,
        "reserved_in_bytes" : 0
      },
      "indexing" : {
        "index_total" : 35049143,
        "index_time_in_millis" : 93342006,
        "index_current" : 1,
        "index_failed" : 7,
        "delete_total" : 28158400,
        "delete_time_in_millis" : 2241164,
        "delete_current" : 0,
        "noop_update_total" : 108,
        "is_throttled" : false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
      },
      "get" : {
        "total" : 8272612,
        "time_in_millis" : 9407739,
        "exists_total" : 7714730,
        "exists_time_in_millis" : 6864869,
        "missing_total" : 557882,
        "missing_time_in_millis" : 2542870,
        "current" : 0
      },
      "search" : {
        "open_contexts" : 99,
        "query_total" : 781661,
        "query_time_in_millis" : 46180985,
        "query_current" : 0,
        "fetch_total" : 25828,
        "fetch_time_in_millis" : 31922549,
        "fetch_current" : 0,
        "scroll_total" : 150005,
        "scroll_time_in_millis" : 3934488045,
        "scroll_current" : 99,
        "suggest_total" : 0,
        "suggest_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "suggest_current" : 0
      },
      "merges" : {
        "current" : 0,
        "current_docs" : 0,
        "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
        "total" : 5069,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 15670663,
        "total_docs" : 232287891,
        "total_size_in_bytes" : 144734357228,
        "total_stopped_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "total_throttled_time_in_millis" : 3012035,
        "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes" : 1635281344
      },
      "refresh" : {
        "total" : 26258,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 24294337,
        "external_total" : 23116,
        "external_total_time_in_millis" : 51934585,
        "listeners" : 0
      },
      "flush" : {
        "total" : 129,
        "periodic" : 29,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 83553
      },
      "warmer" : {
        "current" : 0,
        "total" : 23099,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 28150896
      },
      "query_cache" : {
        "memory_size_in_bytes" : 1971367836,
        "total_count" : 5941141,
        "hit_count" : 1281540,
        "miss_count" : 4659601,
        "cache_size" : 34136,
        "cache_count" : 34655,
        "evictions" : 519
      },
      "fielddata" : {
        "memory_size_in_bytes" : 2270860360,
        "evictions" : 0
      },
      "completion" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 0
      },
      "segments" : {
        "count" : 3062,
        "memory_in_bytes" : 686053834,
        "terms_memory_in_bytes" : 583830952,
        "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes" : 2159936,
        "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
        "norms_memory_in_bytes" : 84022720,
        "points_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
        "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 16040226,
        "index_writer_memory_in_bytes" : 3083169874,
        "version_map_memory_in_bytes" : 14212574,
        "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes" : 441678080,
        "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp" : -1,
        "file_sizes" : { }
      },
      "translog" : {
        "operations" : 1145991,
        "size_in_bytes" : 1862599220,
        "uncommitted_operations" : 1145991,
        "uncommitted_size_in_bytes" : 1862599220,
        "earliest_last_modified_age" : 10
      },
      "request_cache" : {
        "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
        "evictions" : 0,
        "hit_count" : 692,
        "miss_count" : 7824
      },
      "recovery" : {
        "current_as_source" : 0,
        "current_as_target" : 0,
        "throttle_time_in_millis" : 146589584
      }
    },
    "total" : {
      "docs" : {
        "count" : 5528419715,
        "deleted" : 1568758887
      },
      "store" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 3779599075512,
        "reserved_in_bytes" : 0
      },
      "indexing" : {
        "index_total" : 65246167,
        "index_time_in_millis" : 116379853,
        "index_current" : 2,
        "index_failed" : 7,
        "delete_total" : 56316800,
        "delete_time_in_millis" : 4569453,
        "delete_current" : 0,
        "noop_update_total" : 108,
        "is_throttled" : false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
      },
      "get" : {
        "total" : 8279717,
        "time_in_millis" : 9461541,
        "exists_total" : 7721681,
        "exists_time_in_millis" : 6917878,
        "missing_total" : 558036,
        "missing_time_in_millis" : 2543663,
        "current" : 0
      },
      "search" : {
        "open_contexts" : 200,
        "query_total" : 1421264,
        "query_time_in_millis" : 84711977,
        "query_current" : 0,
        "fetch_total" : 47121,
        "fetch_time_in_millis" : 55494456,
        "fetch_current" : 2,
        "scroll_total" : 282690,
        "scroll_time_in_millis" : 6909135621,
        "scroll_current" : 200,
        "suggest_total" : 0,
        "suggest_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "suggest_current" : 0
      },
      "merges" : {
        "current" : 0,
        "current_docs" : 0,
        "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
        "total" : 8563,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 30676821,
        "total_docs" : 452795172,
        "total_size_in_bytes" : 273814327525,
        "total_stopped_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "total_throttled_time_in_millis" : 6337362,
        "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes" : 3305840977
      },
      "refresh" : {
        "total" : 47329,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 46367778,
        "external_total" : 43783,
        "external_total_time_in_millis" : 98641382,
        "listeners" : 0
      },
      "flush" : {
        "total" : 298,
        "periodic" : 98,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 210368
      },
      "warmer" : {
        "current" : 0,
        "total" : 43760,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 52941301
      },
      "query_cache" : {
        "memory_size_in_bytes" : 3882183058,
        "total_count" : 10826442,
        "hit_count" : 2195511,
        "miss_count" : 8630931,
        "cache_size" : 66063,
        "cache_count" : 66884,
        "evictions" : 821
      },
      "fielddata" : {
        "memory_size_in_bytes" : 4524309840,
        "evictions" : 0
      },
      "completion" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 0
      },
      "segments" : {
        "count" : 6121,
        "memory_in_bytes" : 1359222728,
        "terms_memory_in_bytes" : 1155693088,
        "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes" : 4324024,
        "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
        "norms_memory_in_bytes" : 166294144,
        "points_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
        "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 32911472,
        "index_writer_memory_in_bytes" : 5666776518,
        "version_map_memory_in_bytes" : 26231773,
        "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes" : 887417576,
        "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp" : -1,
        "file_sizes" : { }
      },
      "translog" : {
        "operations" : 31206542,
        "size_in_bytes" : 28262050766,
        "uncommitted_operations" : 31206542,
        "uncommitted_size_in_bytes" : 28262050766,
        "earliest_last_modified_age" : 10
      },
      "request_cache" : {
        "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
        "evictions" : 0,
        "hit_count" : 1296,
        "miss_count" : 13655
      },
      "recovery" : {
        "current_as_source" : 0,
        "current_as_target" : 0,
        "throttle_time_in_millis" : 229545608
      }
    }
  },
  "indices" : {
    "segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571" : {
      "uuid" : "fhZUqTwfSeum3hHlyFaILw",
      "primaries" : {
        "docs" : {
          "count" : 2764210965,
          "deleted" : 768121801
        },
        "store" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 1882036902899,
          "reserved_in_bytes" : 0
        },
        "indexing" : {
          "index_total" : 35049143,
          "index_time_in_millis" : 93342006,
          "index_current" : 1,
          "index_failed" : 7,
          "delete_total" : 28158400,
          "delete_time_in_millis" : 2241164,
          "delete_current" : 0,
          "noop_update_total" : 108,
          "is_throttled" : false,
          "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
        },
        "get" : {
          "total" : 8272612,
          "time_in_millis" : 9407739,
          "exists_total" : 7714730,
          "exists_time_in_millis" : 6864869,
          "missing_total" : 557882,
          "missing_time_in_millis" : 2542870,
          "current" : 0
        },
        "search" : {
          "open_contexts" : 99,
          "query_total" : 781661,
          "query_time_in_millis" : 46180985,
          "query_current" : 0,
          "fetch_total" : 25828,
          "fetch_time_in_millis" : 31922549,
          "fetch_current" : 0,
          "scroll_total" : 150005,
          "scroll_time_in_millis" : 3934488045,
          "scroll_current" : 99,
          "suggest_total" : 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "suggest_current" : 0
        },
        "merges" : {
          "current" : 0,
          "current_docs" : 0,
          "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "total" : 5069,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 15670663,
          "total_docs" : 232287891,
          "total_size_in_bytes" : 144734357228,
          "total_stopped_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "total_throttled_time_in_millis" : 3012035,
          "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes" : 1635281344
        },
        "refresh" : {
          "total" : 26258,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 24294337,
          "external_total" : 23116,
          "external_total_time_in_millis" : 51934585,
          "listeners" : 0
        },
        "flush" : {
          "total" : 129,
          "periodic" : 29,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 83553
        },
        "warmer" : {
          "current" : 0,
          "total" : 23099,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 28150896
        },
        "query_cache" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 1971367836,
          "total_count" : 5941141,
          "hit_count" : 1281540,
          "miss_count" : 4659601,
          "cache_size" : 34136,
          "cache_count" : 34655,
          "evictions" : 519
        },
        "fielddata" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 2270860360,
          "evictions" : 0
        },
        "completion" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 0
        },
        "segments" : {
          "count" : 3062,
          "memory_in_bytes" : 686053834,
          "terms_memory_in_bytes" : 583830952,
          "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes" : 2159936,
          "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
          "norms_memory_in_bytes" : 84022720,
          "points_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
          "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 16040226,
          "index_writer_memory_in_bytes" : 3083169874,
          "version_map_memory_in_bytes" : 14212574,
          "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes" : 441678080,
          "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp" : -1,
          "file_sizes" : { }
        },
        "translog" : {
          "operations" : 1145991,
          "size_in_bytes" : 1862599220,
          "uncommitted_operations" : 1145991,
          "uncommitted_size_in_bytes" : 1862599220,
          "earliest_last_modified_age" : 10
        },
        "request_cache" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "evictions" : 0,
          "hit_count" : 692,
          "miss_count" : 7824
        },
        "recovery" : {
          "current_as_source" : 0,
          "current_as_target" : 0,
          "throttle_time_in_millis" : 146589584
        }
      },
      "total" : {
        "docs" : {
          "count" : 5528419715,
          "deleted" : 1568758887
        },
        "store" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 3779599075512,
          "reserved_in_bytes" : 0
        },
        "indexing" : {
          "index_total" : 65246167,
          "index_time_in_millis" : 116379853,
          "index_current" : 2,
          "index_failed" : 7,
          "delete_total" : 56316800,
          "delete_time_in_millis" : 4569453,
          "delete_current" : 0,
          "noop_update_total" : 108,
          "is_throttled" : false,
          "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
        },
        "get" : {
          "total" : 8279717,
          "time_in_millis" : 9461541,
          "exists_total" : 7721681,
          "exists_time_in_millis" : 6917878,
          "missing_total" : 558036,
          "missing_time_in_millis" : 2543663,
          "current" : 0
        },
        "search" : {
          "open_contexts" : 200,
          "query_total" : 1421264,
          "query_time_in_millis" : 84711977,
          "query_current" : 0,
          "fetch_total" : 47121,
          "fetch_time_in_millis" : 55494456,
          "fetch_current" : 2,
          "scroll_total" : 282690,
          "scroll_time_in_millis" : 6909135621,
          "scroll_current" : 200,
          "suggest_total" : 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "suggest_current" : 0
        },
        "merges" : {
          "current" : 0,
          "current_docs" : 0,
          "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "total" : 8563,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 30676821,
          "total_docs" : 452795172,
          "total_size_in_bytes" : 273814327525,
          "total_stopped_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "total_throttled_time_in_millis" : 6337362,
          "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes" : 3305840977
        },
        "refresh" : {
          "total" : 47329,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 46367778,
          "external_total" : 43783,
          "external_total_time_in_millis" : 98641382,
          "listeners" : 0
        },
        "flush" : {
          "total" : 298,
          "periodic" : 98,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 210368
        },
        "warmer" : {
          "current" : 0,
          "total" : 43760,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 52941301
        },
        "query_cache" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 3882183058,
          "total_count" : 10826442,
          "hit_count" : 2195511,
          "miss_count" : 8630931,
          "cache_size" : 66063,
          "cache_count" : 66884,
          "evictions" : 821
        },
        "fielddata" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 4524309840,
          "evictions" : 0
        },
        "completion" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 0
        },
        "segments" : {
          "count" : 6121,
          "memory_in_bytes" : 1359222728,
          "terms_memory_in_bytes" : 1155693088,
          "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes" : 4324024,
          "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
          "norms_memory_in_bytes" : 166294144,
          "points_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
          "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 32911472,
          "index_writer_memory_in_bytes" : 5666776518,
          "version_map_memory_in_bytes" : 26231773,
          "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes" : 887417576,
          "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp" : -1,
          "file_sizes" : { }
        },
        "translog" : {
          "operations" : 31206542,
          "size_in_bytes" : 28262050766,
          "uncommitted_operations" : 31206542,
          "uncommitted_size_in_bytes" : 28262050766,
          "earliest_last_modified_age" : 10
        },
        "request_cache" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "evictions" : 0,
          "hit_count" : 1296,
          "miss_count" : 13655
        },
        "recovery" : {
          "current_as_source" : 0,
          "current_as_target" : 0,
          "throttle_time_in_millis" : 229545608
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Would request to guide me with an appropriate approach as to what are best ways to deal with this and optimise the search performance

Comment: OS v7.10.2 is not available, are you using Elasticsearch ?

Comment: my opensearch domain is under the hood using elasticsearch v7.10

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do in such cases is to run forcemerge and only expunge deleted docs

```
POST _forcemerge?only_expunge_deletes=true
```

Since the ratio of deleted/total docs is ~30% that should allow you to regain some space...

Try it out on a single index first. Record the size before and after  and you should see some space gained.

Comment: sure, I had a doubt regarding the the number of segments that it would make but as you clarified that It would try and half the number of already existing segments, also as per docs I would have to stop indexing, updating of docs till the time this force merge completes, and searching can run simultaneously?

Comment: Also Is there a possibility here that merged segments can be of size like 10GB or 15GB also, which could lead to some performance issues?

Comment: When only expunging deletes, there are usually no merge happening, at least not big ones. Since the `index.merge.policy.max_merged_segment` setting is set to 5gb by default, there's no reason that bigger segments get created in the process.

Comment: Ideally you should stop indexing, but it also works while indexing, it takes more time though... searches can also happen during the merge, like in any normal situation since merges are happening all the time anyway

Comment: On running this command POST segment_index_570de84a4f0d925f98343571/_forcemerge?only_expunge_deletes=true&wait_for_completion=false, ES throws an exception that wait_for_completion is an unrecognized parameter, can't understand why as its mentioned in docs?

Comment: seems to me as it was not supported in previous versions, also I can't find ony_expunge_deletes in the doc but it seems to be working.

Comment: @YashTandon looks like you are looking at wrong version documentation, see in 7.10 wait_for_completion is not listed https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/indices-forcemerge.html

Comment: @YashTandon Also I see `ony_expunge_deletes` is mentioned in 7.10 as well as latest version of Elasticsearch (8.4)

Comment: @Val I ran this and segments size has increased as I can see segments of size 8-10Gb as well

Comment: IME this command always times out regardless of what you send it. But it still works.

Comment: @datashaman Most of the time a force merge will take time depending on the size of your index, but if you don't want to wait and run the risk of a timeout, you can specify `&wait_for_completion=false` and the command will return immediately and show you the ID of the task that is now running asynchronously. You can then check the progress of the force merge task using `GET _tasks/<task_id>`